# Set default value based on column in another table during migration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Trying to change my database a little bit. I have two tables one called `User` and one called `Plan`. I want to perform a migration that will add a column to my `User` table and set the default value of that column based on the value of a column in the `Plan` table. Then drop the `Plan` table along with any other columns in the `User` table that were associated with `Plan`. The following is the code that I have so far, but I am not sure if it is the best approach.

```
class DropPlansAddPurchasedAuctionsToCompany < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :users, :purchased_items, :integer, default: 0, after: :legal_name
    User.update_all(:purchased_items => -1).where("plan_id IS NOT NULL")
    remove_column :users, :plan_id
    remove_column :users, :plan_started_at
    remove_column :users, :disable_plan_limits
    drop_table :plans
  end

  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration, "Can't recover plans table"
  end
end
```

I think this is the right direction but when I run the migration i get the following error message: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'where' for 3:Fixnum`

Any insight or suggestions? If you need more info I can provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update_all` returns the number of records that were updated, which is a number, not a relation.
You should do the `where` before the `update_all`:

`User.where("plan_id IS NOT NULL").update_all(:purchased_items => -1)`